# Python: Count Values In Nested Dictionary

Tags: python

I have a nested dictionary, and need to get the sum of its values. The dictionary looks like:

```
d = {'i am': {'i am sam' : 3,
             'i am jack' : 4},
     'he is' : {'he is alex' : 2,
              'he is adam' : 1}
    }
```

If I want to find the total instances of `d['he is']`, I can do the following, but it gets very slow as the dictionary gets larger. Is there a more efficient way to do this?

```
d_count = sum(d['he is'].values())
```

Comment: Why do you think It would get slower ? `d['he is']` is already giving `O(1)` complexity and you need all values so `.values()` is efficient I think.

Comment: In actuality, this is part of  a loop, with thousands of words, and thousands of iterations. It's very slow, taking at least a few minutes to complete.

Comment: @Adam_G: and the dictionary sum is the part that makes this slow?

Comment: @Adam_G: if so, then you should look for other data structures; a database would be a better option. Summing all values in a `dict`, nested or not, is not going to be any faster than this.

Comment: Thanks. Do you have an example of an alternative data structure?

Comment: @Adam_G if it's possible, showing more of your code may help us identify other things that may be significantly larger bottlenecks.

Comment: Python comes with the `sqlite3` database driver.

Comment: Is there no way to maintain a running total as you are creating the dict. `d={<key>: [<d_count>, <dict_of values>]`

Comment: That's an interesting idea. I'd just need to make sure it doesn't confuse that count pairing with the other word string pairings, e.g. the word "count". I'll think about that

Comment: If you're concerned about performance, python isn't really your best choice :/